# Adding CPUs accessible by docker for TensorFlow on Windows 10

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm using Tensorflow on windows 10 with docker (yes, I know Windows 10 isn't supported yet).  It performs ok, but only looks like I am only accessing just one of my cpu cores (I have 8).  Tensorflow has the ability to assign ops to different devices, so I'd like to be able to get access to all 8.  In VirtualBox when I view the settings it only says there is 1 cpu out of the 8 that is configured for the machine.  I tried editing the machine to set it to more, but that lead to all sorts of weirdness.

Does anyone know the right way to either create or restart a docker machine to have 8 CPUs?   I'm  using the docker quickstart container app.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

First you need to ensure you have enabled Virtualization for your machine. You have to do that in the BIOS of your computer.

The link below has a nice video on how to do that, but there are others as well if you google it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFJYpT7L5ag

Then you have to stop the docker machine (i.e. the VirtualBox vm) and change the CPU configuration in VirtualBox.

To list the name of your docker machine (it is usually `default`) run:

```
docker-machine ls
```

Then stop the docker machine:

```
docker-machine stop <machine name>
```

Next open VirtualBox UI and change the number of CPUs:

- Select the docker virtual machine (should be marked as Powered off)
- Click Settings->Systems->Processors
- Change the number of CPUs
- Click OK to save your changes

Restart the docker machine:

```
docker-machine start <machine name>
```

Finally you can use the CPU constraint options available for `docker run` command to restrict CPU usage for your containers if desired.

For example the following command restrict container to use only 3 CPUs:

```
docker run -ti --cpuset-cpus="0-2" ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash
```

More details available in the docker run reference document [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources).

Comment: Many thanks!  Are you on windows 10?  This is more or less what I had done before but it doesn't seem to work.  Officially, docker doesn't support windows 10 yet, so perhaps this is something that still needs to be worked out.

Comment: No I am not on Windows 10. I am OSX now, but used to work with Windows 7 recently. Although docker is not officially supported on Windows 10 yet, the virtualization steps depends on your hardware and VirtualBox only. VirtualBox 5 is supported on Windows 10, see here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/virtualbox/support/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I just create the machine with all cpus

docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-cpu-count=-1 dev

-1 means use all available cpus.